# How to check if time is less than or equal to particular hour in java script

Tags: javascript, time

I am trying to validate if the given time value is less than or equal to 13

i get the values from UI like `hour and minutes and am/pm`.

how do i check if total hours does not exceed 13 in javascript?

after some calculation i have hour and minutes and i tried to validate as follows

```
if ((fromHour != 13 & fromMinute == 0) & (toHour < fromHour & toMinute == 0)) //  
                {
                    alert("Time cannot be greater than 13 hours"); 
}
```

but it is not working as i expected.

could someone help pls.

Comment: Are you asking about the time between `fromHour:fromMinute` and `toHour:toMinute`? Can the times cross over midnight?

Comment: @Barmar Yes is the answer for both the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the times to minutes by multiplying the hour by 60 and adding the minutes. Then subtract the times and see if it's less than `13*60`. And if the times cross over midnight, so that the `to` time is lower than the `from` time, add the number of minutes in a day first.

```
fromTime = fromHour * 60 + fromMinute;
toTime = toHour * 60 * toMinute;
if (toTime < fromTime) {
    toTime += 60*24;
}
if (toTime - fromTime > 13*60) {
    alert("Time cannot be greater than 13 hours");
}
```